# How do I enter full_path and path_extension using the import package in Windows?

Tags: windows, import

How do I enter full_path and path_extension using the import package?

I am using Windows and want to point to c:\tex\proj\pic\alpha having proj as the directory hosting the tex file (I would like to point to pic\alpha relative to proj with path_extension).

I tried c/tex/proj/pic/alpha and c:\tex\proj\pic\alpha as full_path but it didn't help me find the file beta.tex_pdf in alpha directory. The file beta.pdf_tex was created by Inkscape.

```
\usepackage{import}

\import{c/tex/proj/pic/alpha}{beta.pdf_tex}%File `beta.pdf_tex' not found.
```

I can't figure out how to make a MWE out of this.

Edit:

```
\begin{figure}[!th]
   \centering   
   \def\svgwidth{5cm}
   \input{beta.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

This works but then I have to put beta.pdf_tex in the same folder as the tex file.

Comment: I think you don't have to include `c/tex/proj`, just simply `pic/alpha`.

Comment: `pdf_text` is not valid file type extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot the semicolon (:) and the trailing / for the absolute path.
The relative path uses \subimport and needs to start with ./ and end with a trailing forward slash.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

    \import{C:/tex/proj/pic/alpha/}{beta.pdf_tex}% Absolute path
    \subimport{./pic/alpha/}{beta.pdf_tex}% Relative path

\end{document}
```

Edit:
Observe that the backward slashes used in Windows ( c:\tex\proj\pic\alpha ) turns into forward slashes. I would avoid using spaces in folder names but if you have to I would try replacing the space with an asterisk (*) in the path used in (La)TeX. Another alternative is to use MS-DOS [8.3 file name format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/142982). If the 8.3 file name format gets you in trouble with tilde (~) you might need to replace for example ~1 with \string~1. The 8.3 format can be seen by using dir /X in cmd (Win+R).